# iPhone - Mimic the capture photo animation?

Tags: iphone

Ive hopped over from the GIS SE site.
I am trying to mock up some iPhone dummy apps in photoshop for a presentation.
I already found [this great link](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/tools-for-creating-mockups-for-mobile-device-uis) on this site, but have a more specific Q.

When you take a photo on an iPhone, that animation happens where the lens closes on the main screen and then opens again.
- I want to get hold of this animation so I can overlay it onto my PSD template in photoshop.
I aim to then embed this in either powerpoint or within Adobe After Effects.

Any ideas?

Comment: What if you pointed the camera at something totally black, in the dark, and then took a photo while recording the screen output of the iPhone onto your Mac or whatever? Then you'd be able to isolate the black (or some other colour) and make that transparent so the result would be a video of that animation, which you could then export to some other format.

Comment: Also, try asking this question on apple.stackexchange.com - they might be geeky enough to know answers to superspecific questions like this. :)

Comment: Thanks Rahul.  Good idea, although I am skeptical on the quality of the output I would get.  Im thinking there must be one already on the www somewhere, just cant pin it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the static image, but will it work for you? (Click for full 960x640 goodness)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this [stock animation of a shutter opening and closing](http://www.pond5.com/stock-footage/148727/camera-shutter-opening-and-closing.html). Would it be of any use as an approximation if you can't find the exact iPhone animation?