# Two step selection in windows phone 7

Tags: lists, guidelines, windows-phone-7

How to display this two step selection dialog in a **native** way in WP7:

1. States (in my case approximately 40 entries)
2. Cities (in my case 1-15 entries)

Here are my thoughts I want to discuss with you guys. You probably won't be able to read the descriptions. [So, check the source on gdocs. Feel free to make changes.](https://docs.google.com/drawings/edit?id=1XY9DLv7p2WV6nDLs-H3OAz0vlTcfPTkcp09M5kF1-Hs&hl=en) (I still keep a [read only version](https://docs.google.com/drawings/edit?id=1mxIXcnpsw5CHGJcG_auDwQNR_pMtpMRYaOWIuGwqdb8&hl=en).)

[image]

Will the word "states" irritate my users?

[Details to Quick Jump Selection](https://blogs.claritycon.com/kevinmarshall/2010/10/06/wp7-quick-jump-grid-sample-code/)

Comment: Just learnt that A is against the guidelines (http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Jaime+Rodriguez/Windows-Phone-Design-Days-Pivot-and-Pano/ at 16:00) The video also recommends D for a wizard flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think D is the most appropriate choice and most "WP7-like" and is also going to give the best perceived performance to the user. In the solutions where all of the states and all of their cities are loaded at once you are loading much more data in one go.

Something that I've implemented in WP7 apps for similar "wizard" style interfaces is to use two separate lists and to animate between the two instead of actually navigating to a separate page. That way, you only load the data that's needed when it's needed, but the user doesn't have to wait for the page navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, I think option B and D would feel most at home on windows phone 7.

Option D would be the more generic one, where one selects a specific state/city, while option B is a bit different in that it allows you to "shop around" for a state/city combo.

This would feel more appropriate in a case where the user is not decided on the state/city: (s)he searches for a destination for the upcoming vacation for example (not a very good example).

Comment: In my case, the users are very decided. Mostlikely they search their metropol of choice in their surrounding. Have u ever seen C and A?

Comment: Can't say that I have