# What software is used to create GUI concept videos?

Tags: gui-design, wireframe, mockup, video, animation

If I was to create a prototype or video of a GUI concept with animations, what software is best suited for that? The focus would be applications for mobile devices or screens integrated in homes, cars etc.

Comment: What kind of GUI? Web? Desktop? Physical? Mechanical? Futuristic theory?

Comment: @DA01 I updated the question with information on what applications the GUI would be used in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question quite a long time ago. Since 2012 many applications have entered the market. I'll list a few here below and since they are frequently updated I'm deliberately avoiding describing pros and cons with the different ones. I have probably missed a few, please leave a comment with the ones you feel should be in this list.

- [Principle](https://principleformac.com/)
- [Framer](https://www.framer.com/)
- [ProtoPie](https://www.protopie.io/)

Modern UI design tools like [Sketch](https://www.sketch.com/), [Adobe XD](https://www.adobe.com/products/xd.html) and [Figma](https://figma.com) have prototyping features that will allow you to create simple screen transitions.

Then there are tools like Adobe After Effects that will step it up another level and do video effects as well as vector animation. But it will not do interactive prototypes.

For 3D UI animations there is Blender, Cinema 4D, 3D Studio Max etc. But they are generally not focused on application design.

Answer (score 5):

The best solution I can think of would be Keynote/PowerPoint. Keynote is especially well-suited for this task because its animation options are very comprehensive and you can export to a QuickTime/H.264 video including animations, transitions, etc.

The alternative is to simply screen record mockups you've put together in HTML or some other mockup tool using something like Camtasia on Windows or QuickTime Player X on Mac.

Comment: For the screen recording part, you can also use Jing. It's free and works on Mac and Windows. It doesn't have any editing capabilities though.

Answer (score 3):

I understand you look for a mock up tool that produces an animated result. Mocking in that high level is rare, as in most cases it takes too much time and [normal, "still" wireframing](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/tools-for-creating-mockups-for-mobile-device-uis) does the most important job anyway: providing something to point at while explaining.

But, I got three favs, if I really want my peeps to see how it animates:

- Flash,
- Powerpoint,
- Stop motion with pen, paper and some app for stop motion.

Comment: The reason I approved the other answer over yours was due to the ability to export to video in Keynote. Thanks for the quick answer!